# Open form in new tab on submit click

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, submit

I have come across similar questions on here but none that directly refer to the one i am looking for. So i have a form div with target="_blank". When clicking an Input submit link i would like the form to open in a new tab.

I have some javascript code in the background that manipulates the form item based on buttons to give different options. When the submit button is clicked i would like the form values to be correctly passed with the form and to open in a new tab.

If i disable Javascript the form correctly opens in a new tab, so the Javascript is blocking the new tab. How can i get my form to open correctly whilst passing the option values with the form?

Some example code:

```
<form id="search" name="search" action="www.search.com" target="_blank" method="post">
...
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Search" class="button">
```

Also why would Javascript be blocking the new tab popup?

Comment: I can't actually disclose the JS itself but all it is doing is manipulating the form values and style based on the option a user clicks. It in no way is called when the form is submitted so do not know why it is blocking the popup.

Comment: I honestly think it's something js related. Made something super quick based off your description and it doesn't seem to be an issue: http://jsfiddle.net/hf35X/. If your js is manipulating the form at all, make sure it doesn't remove the target="_blank" part. As part of testing this you could add the target=blank attribute through js on form submit - see what happens.

Comment: I am using Drupal for my build. Have disabled the form JS and still the same issue. Have even used jQuery to force the target by using $('#search').get(0).setAttribute('target', '_blank');. So it seems some other JS is blocking the new tab

Answer (score 2):

try this for Open form in new tab on submit click

```
<input type="submit" target="_blank" name="commit" value="Search" class="button">
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Have you tried calling your JavaScript function like this?

```
<form id="search" name="search" action="www.search.com" target="_blank" method="post" onSubmit="return function();">
```

Edit: After this call, you can do your field settings on JS and if everything is alright, just return true for the form to be submitted, or false to cancel submission.

Comment: I have tried this method and adding a JS function call to the input but it opens one in a new window and the original tab where the link is called gets executed aswell.

Comment: I am afraid that, without taking a look into your JS code I won't be able to provide any more help.